# Class inside echo

Tags: php, echo

Is there anyway this can be simplified?

```
<?php
    $menu = JSite::getMenu(); 
    $arr = (array)$menu->getActive(); 
    $alias = $arr['alias'];

    if ($alias == "accueil") {
        echo('<h2 class="moduletitle"><span>title 1</h2></span>');
    }
   elseif ($alias == "welcome") {
       echo('<h2 class="moduletitle"><span>title 2</h2></span>');
   }
   else {
       echo "<h1 class='moduletitle'><span>";
       echo $this->escape($this->params->get('page_title'));
       echo "</span></h1>";
   }
?>
```

Comment: If this is a working code, you may want to try [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You never explained what the above code does. How can we help?  Also this question does not belong here. Check code review as @Swellar noted

Comment: this should be closed, as it's not clear what OP is asking

Comment: @Amrinder: regarding your edit here, please don't use Snippet devices for code that won't run in a browser. JavaScript, CSS and HTML are generally fine (assuming they produce runnable output) but PHP is not. (This has been fixed by another editor).

Answer (score 1):

At least try to use switch instead of many if else:

```
<?php
$menu = JSite::getMenu(); 
$arr = (array)$menu->getActive(); 
$alias = $arr['alias'];

$headingType = "h1";

switch ($alias) {
    case 'accueil':
        $headingType = "h2";
        $title = "title 1";
        break;

    case 'welcome':
        $headingType = "h2";
        $title = "title 2";
        break;

    default:
        $title = $this->escape($this->params->get('page_title'));
}

echo "<" . $headingType . " class=\"moduletitle\"><span>" . 
$title . 
"</span></" . $headingType . ">";
```